# Django: Automatically logged in as Admin after runserver

Tags: django

Good day SO!

I am a beginner in Django, and I am facing a small problem but I do not know where to start in Debugging it.

After executing 'manage.py runserver', I will be automatically logged in as the Administrator account I created via createsuperuser.

How do I fix this issue? Any clue on where I should start looking? Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you! Will provide any details necessary

Comment: How do you know that you're already logged in?

Comment: I will automatically redirect a user to the main page if he is logged in, and to the login page otherwise. I somehow managed to find the problem as well. Despite closing the Chrome browser, the session somehow still got maintained. I had to kill the entire Chrome application via task mgr. Sorry for the inconvenience :)